# Import error for numpy

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, fft, fftpack

I downloaded `numpy1.8` for `python 2.7`
Installed fine, but when i give:

```
from numpy.fft import fft, fftfreq
```

it gives me a huge error, which ends with

```
from numpy.core.multiarray import (
ImportError: cannot import name datetime_data
```

How can i get rid of this error ?
I need `numpy` to perform `fft` functions.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to install from source, or are you installing packages via your operating system?

Comment: Does `import numpy` run without error?

Comment: import numpy also gives the same error, i suspect its a problem with the numpy installation, but then i tried numpy from various sites.. i still get the same error.